# Very small regional Yajilin

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #14: Think inside the (very small) box!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/monthly-topic-challenge-14-think-inside-the-very-small-box).</sub>

---

Rules of regional Yajilin:

- Shade some cells in the grid. Two shaded cells cannot share an edge, but can touch at a corner.
- Draw a single loop, going horizontally and vertically through centres of cells, which visits every unshaded cell and none of the shaded cells. The loop cannot cross itself or branch out.
- A number in the top-left corner of a cage marked with dotted lines indicates how many shaded cells are inside the cage.

[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/yr4z3dk6)

[image: Empty regional Yajilin grid]

Comment: "Draw a single loop, going horizontally and vertically through centres of cells, which visits every unshaded cell in the grid." - and only the unshaded cells?

Comment: Shaded cells can only appear in the numbered regions?

Comment: @user2357112 Good point, the loop can't pass through shaded cells. I've clarified the rules now.

Comment: @justhalf Shaded cells can be anywhere, not necessarily inside a cage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [image]

> The only way to get a loop into and out of the 3-cage without its getting stuck is by darkening those three squares. Once that's done, the only way to get a loop into and out of the 2-cage without its getting stuck is by darkening those two squares.

Answer (score 12):

The completed grid:

> [image]

The solve path:

> First, look at the 3-cage:
>
> Note that diagonally adjacent shaded cells would always leave a dead-end cell in row 5. So the shaded cells must be in columns 1, 3 and 5.
>
> Then the shaded cells in columns 1 and 5 must be in row 5 to avoid dead-end cells in row 5.
>
> And then the shaded cell in column 3 must be in row 4 to avoid more dead-end cells in row 5.
>  And that forces all the shaded cells in the 3-cage.

> Now for the 2-cage:
>
> Similarly to the above, we cannot have diagonally adjacent shaded cells in rows 1 and 2.
>
> So there must be a shaded cell in row 3, which can only be in column 2.
>
> The other shaded cell must be in row 1, and it cannot be in column 2 (dead-end cell in R1C1), so must be R1C3.

> That gives us all the shaded cells in the cages.
>  From there the loop path is forced.